# Ray diagram of infinity well

Tags: geometric-optics

An [infinity well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnapcNUIhoI) works on the principle that when two plane mirrors are placed in front of each other an infinite number of images are produced thus creating an illusion.I am a bit confused about it's ray diagram.Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram. I'm not sure if it is important to make the separation of the mirrors match the diameter to get a nicer effect.

[image]